# Nowdoc Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_SL

Tags: php, heredoc, nowdoc

```
$default_post = <<<'DEFAULT_POST'
<div itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/VideoObject'>
<meta itemprop='name' content="%VideoTitle%"><meta itemprop='thumbnailURL' content='%VideoImage%'><meta itemprop='embedURL' content='%VideoUrl%'><meta itemprop='width' content='640'><meta itemprop='height' content='480'><meta itemprop='duration' content='%VideoDuration8601%'>
<p style='text-align:center;'>[embed width='640' height='480']%VideoUrl%[/embed]</p>
<p><span itemprop='description'>%VideoDescription%</span></p>
</div>
DEFAULT_POST;
```

The first line is the one throwing the error. I have this code running on 100s of sites but I have one customer who reports this error.

There is no whitespace after the nowdoc 'DEFAULT_POST'.

Customer states he is running PHP 5.3.29 (nowdoc introduced in 5.3.0).

So now I'm at a loss. Looking for other ideas on what this might be...

Comment: Your syntax is fine, I think that the problem is in the PHP version and that the customer is reporting the wrong one.

Comment: I'll try to verify that without being a jerk.

Comment: I've uploaded a phpinfo file to his server and verified PHP 5.3.29 BUT I also noticed PHP API is 20090626. Does that mean this version of PHP was compiled with old libraries from June 2009, possibly before nowdoc was included?